# Why is $\frac{1}{j^{p}} \le \int_{j-1}^{j} \frac{dx}{x^p}$?

Tags: calculus, integration, sequences-and-series, complex-analysis

> Prove that the power series $\sum_{j=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{z^{j}}{j^{2}}$ converges at every point on its circle of convergence $|z|=1$

In order to prove the last statement, I'm supposed to first show the next result:

$$\text{For}~j \ge 2,\quad\frac1{ j^p } \le \int_{j-1}^{j} \frac{dx}{x^p}.$$

Although, I don't really understand why $\dfrac1{j^p} \le \int_{j-1}^{j} \dfrac{dx}{x^p}.$

Comment: The length of the interval $[j-1,j]$ is $1$. If $x$ is in this interval, then $1/x^p\ge 1/j^p$. Then use the trivial estimate for the integral:  $\int\ge$ width of the interval $\times$ minimum of the function. All this assuming $p>0$.

Comment: So, $\int_{j-1}^{j}\dfrac{1}{x^{p}} \ge \dfrac{1}{max(x^{p})} = \dfrac{1}{j^{p}}$?

Comment: @K.M yes, exactly

Comment: "... converges at no point ... " It is absolutely convergent for each $z$ with $\lvert z \rvert = 1$.

Answer (score 1):

To show that
$\dfrac1{j^p} \le \int_{j-1}^{j} \dfrac{dx}{x^p}.
$
you also need $p \ge 0$.

The basic idea
is that
the average value of a function
over an interval
is between its
min and max.

As a formula,
$\min(f(x))|_a^b
\le \dfrac1{b-a}\int_a^b f(x) dx
\le\max(f(x))|_a^b
$.

If $f$ is increasing,
this becomes
$f(a)
\le \dfrac1{b-a}\int_a^b f(x) dx
\le f(b)
$;
if $f$ is decreasing then
$f(a)
\ge \dfrac1{b-a}\int_a^b f(x) dx
\ge f(b)
$.

If $f(x) = \dfrac1{x^p}$
with $p > 0$
and $x > 0$,
then $f$ is decreasing.
Setting $a=j-1, b=j$,
then
$\dfrac1{b-a} = 1$
so this becomes
$\dfrac1{(j-1)^p}
\ge\int_{j-1}^j f(x) dx
\ge \dfrac1{j^p}
$.